# InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type bpchar to Char

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am using a PgSQL database with NpgSQL Nuget package.
But when it tries to get some data is shows this error

`InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type bpchar to Char`

I guess that happens because database has a `char` column, and its like a bug of PgSQL, but wanted to know if anyone of you guys have any idea of how to handle that.

p.s `Leg` definition id table is `character` with length of 1

DataController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var model = _repository.Get(20);
    return Ok(model);
}
```

Repository.cs

```
public IEnumerable<VXmlCdr> Get(int howMany)
{
    return _context.VXmlCdr.Take(howMany);
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
        .AddDbContext<fusionpbxContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
```

VXmlCdr.cs

```
public partial class VXmlCdr
{
    public Guid Uuid { get; set; }
    public Guid? DomainUuid { get; set; }
    public Guid? ExtensionUuid { get; set; }
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    public string Accountcode { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public string DefaultLanguage { get; set; }
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public string Xml { get; set; }
    public string Json { get; set; }
    public string CallerIdName { get; set; }
    public string CallerIdNumber { get; set; }
    public string SourceNumber { get; set; }
    public string DestinationNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal? StartEpoch { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartStamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AnswerStamp { get; set; }
    public decimal? AnswerEpoch { get; set; }
    public decimal? EndEpoch { get; set; }
    public string EndStamp { get; set; }
    public decimal? Duration { get; set; }
    public decimal? Mduration { get; set; }
    public decimal? Billsec { get; set; }
    public decimal? Billmsec { get; set; }
    public string BridgeUuid { get; set; }
    public string ReadCodec { get; set; }
    public string ReadRate { get; set; }
    public string WriteCodec { get; set; }
    public string WriteRate { get; set; }
    public string RemoteMediaIp { get; set; }
    public string NetworkAddr { get; set; }
    public string RecordingFile { get; set; }
    public char? Leg { get; set; }
    public decimal? PddMs { get; set; }
    public decimal? RtpAudioInMos { get; set; }
    public string LastApp { get; set; }
    public string LastArg { get; set; }
    public string CcSide { get; set; }
    public Guid? CcMemberUuid { get; set; }
    public string CcQueueJoinedEpoch { get; set; }
    public string CcQueue { get; set; }
    public Guid? CcMemberSessionUuid { get; set; }
    public string CcAgent { get; set; }
    public string CcAgentType { get; set; }
    public decimal? Waitsec { get; set; }
    public string ConferenceName { get; set; }
    public Guid? ConferenceUuid { get; set; }
    public string ConferenceMemberId { get; set; }
    public string DigitsDialed { get; set; }
    public string PinNumber { get; set; }
    public string HangupCause { get; set; }
    public decimal? HangupCauseQ850 { get; set; }
    public string SipHangupDisposition { get; set; }
}
```

Context.cs

```
    public virtual DbSet<VXmlCdr> VXmlCdr { get; set; }

        modelBuilder.Entity<VXmlCdr>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Uuid);

            entity.ToTable("v_xml_cdr");

            entity.Property(e => e.Uuid)
                .HasColumnName("uuid")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.Accountcode).HasColumnName("accountcode");

            entity.Property(e => e.AnswerEpoch).HasColumnName("answer_epoch");

            entity.Property(e => e.AnswerStamp).HasColumnName("answer_stamp");

            entity.Property(e => e.Billmsec).HasColumnName("billmsec");

            entity.Property(e => e.Billsec).HasColumnName("billsec");

            entity.Property(e => e.BridgeUuid).HasColumnName("bridge_uuid");

            entity.Property(e => e.CallerIdName).HasColumnName("caller_id_name");

            entity.Property(e => e.CallerIdNumber).HasColumnName("caller_id_number");

            entity.Property(e => e.CcAgent).HasColumnName("cc_agent");

            entity.Property(e => e.CcAgentType).HasColumnName("cc_agent_type");

            entity.Property(e => e.CcMemberSessionUuid).HasColumnName("cc_member_session_uuid");

            entity.Property(e => e.CcMemberUuid).HasColumnName("cc_member_uuid");

            entity.Property(e => e.CcQueue).HasColumnName("cc_queue");

            entity.Property(e => e.CcQueueJoinedEpoch).HasColumnName("cc_queue_joined_epoch");

            entity.Property(e => e.CcSide).HasColumnName("cc_side");

            entity.Property(e => e.ConferenceMemberId).HasColumnName("conference_member_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.ConferenceName).HasColumnName("conference_name");

            entity.Property(e => e.ConferenceUuid).HasColumnName("conference_uuid");

            entity.Property(e => e.Context).HasColumnName("context");

            entity.Property(e => e.DefaultLanguage).HasColumnName("default_language");

            entity.Property(e => e.DestinationNumber).HasColumnName("destination_number");

            entity.Property(e => e.DigitsDialed).HasColumnName("digits_dialed");

            entity.Property(e => e.Direction).HasColumnName("direction");

            entity.Property(e => e.DomainName).HasColumnName("domain_name");

            entity.Property(e => e.DomainUuid).HasColumnName("domain_uuid");

            entity.Property(e => e.Duration).HasColumnName("duration");

            entity.Property(e => e.EndEpoch).HasColumnName("end_epoch");

            entity.Property(e => e.EndStamp).HasColumnName("end_stamp");

            entity.Property(e => e.ExtensionUuid).HasColumnName("extension_uuid");

            entity.Property(e => e.HangupCause).HasColumnName("hangup_cause");

            entity.Property(e => e.HangupCauseQ850).HasColumnName("hangup_cause_q850");

            entity.Property(e => e.Json)
                .HasColumnName("json")
                .HasColumnType("jsonb");

            entity.Property(e => e.LastApp).HasColumnName("last_app");

            entity.Property(e => e.LastArg).HasColumnName("last_arg");

            entity.Property(e => e.Leg)
                .HasColumnName("leg")
                .HasColumnType("char(1)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Mduration).HasColumnName("mduration");

            entity.Property(e => e.NetworkAddr).HasColumnName("network_addr");

            entity.Property(e => e.PddMs).HasColumnName("pdd_ms");

            entity.Property(e => e.PinNumber).HasColumnName("pin_number");

            entity.Property(e => e.ReadCodec).HasColumnName("read_codec");

            entity.Property(e => e.ReadRate).HasColumnName("read_rate");

            entity.Property(e => e.RecordingFile).HasColumnName("recording_file");

            entity.Property(e => e.RemoteMediaIp).HasColumnName("remote_media_ip");

            entity.Property(e => e.RtpAudioInMos).HasColumnName("rtp_audio_in_mos");

            entity.Property(e => e.SipHangupDisposition).HasColumnName("sip_hangup_disposition");

            entity.Property(e => e.SourceNumber).HasColumnName("source_number");

            entity.Property(e => e.StartEpoch).HasColumnName("start_epoch");

            entity.Property(e => e.StartStamp).HasColumnName("start_stamp");

            entity.Property(e => e.Waitsec).HasColumnName("waitsec");

            entity.Property(e => e.WriteCodec).HasColumnName("write_codec");

            entity.Property(e => e.WriteRate).HasColumnName("write_rate");

            entity.Property(e => e.Xml).HasColumnName("xml");
        });
```

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: No, it's not a database error. In fact, the error message is *different* from what you typed. It says you tried to store a *string* to a `char?`. Post your code and mappings. Most likely you specified `char` instead of `string` as the type of a property

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto just added code also.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yep but i'm not trying to post anything, its just a GET request. p.s. just added code

Comment: The posted code is mostly irrelevant. You need to add your entity code

Comment: @ErtanHasani what does that comment have to do with anything? You posted an error thrown from your data access code. You are using the wrong types. The error is clear. Post your code and mappings.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto just added also that code

Comment: @ErtanHasani and yet, you didn't even check the type of `Leg`. It's `char?`. And I'll bet, the field is NOT a `CHAR(1)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos just added that code from context and entity

Comment: What's the table definition of `Leg`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos should i change that char? to anything else since in DB Leg is `character` with length of 1

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Leg is a `character` with length of 1

Comment: @ErtanHasani What happens if you convert the model to a `string`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto just changed that char? to string and it returns data perfectly. But does that affect anything in POST. when i try to add something there, will it throw any exception database that i'm trying to add string there?

Comment: It shouldn't, in EF (at least while working with SQL Server), all character variations are represented with `string` in the model

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto all right then. Thank you so much.

Comment: `bpchar` is "blank padded char", you can't blank-pad *one* character so this is obviously a string.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yep just made it as string and works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, you should use `string` for character columns:

```
public string Leg { get; set; }
```

Entity Framework will ensure that whatever you assign to `Leg` has a length of 1 when saving changes.